# Add Active Class to Selected Page (With and Without Trailing Slash)

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a selector that is adding the "Active" class to the selected page.
However its only working with the trailing slash, e.g. if its:

Site.com/TEST/ it works fine.

However if its Site.com/TEST it doesnt.

This is causing issues when using "Back" button as it takes me back to the page but without the Trailing "/"

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Can someone amend this to add the class to both variations?
Also, if possible can it be amended so that it adds the active class to the parent, if I select a childpage of the parent?

E.g. Site.com/Test/Edit I would like test to set to active.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.replace(/\/+$/,'') + '/'` will always make sure the string ends with a `/`, so your code would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    str = this.location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/,'') + '/';
    $('a[href="' + str + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

If you don't know if all links end with a slash, then you can check everything:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    str1 = this.location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/,'') + '/';
    str2 = this.location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/,'');
    $('a[href="' + str1 + '"], a[href="' + str2 + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

**EDIT**

Let's try selecting all parent links:

```
var tmp = this.location.pathname.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, "").replace(/\/+$/,'');
arr = tmp.split('/');
while(arr.length > 1) {
  tmp = 'http://' + arr.join('/');
  $('a[href="' + tmp + '"], a[href="' + tmp + '/"]').parent().addClass('active');
  arr = arr.slice(0,-1);
}
```

Basically I am removing the `http://` from the beginning and splitting the string into array elements on every `/`. Then I am removing the end elements one by one, gluing it again and constructing the selector accordingly.

Here it is in action, how it generates the links:

```js
$('#test').click(function(){
  
  // I replaced the string with the input value for testing
  var tmp = $('input').val().replace(/.*?:\/\//g, "").replace(/\/+$/,'');
  arr = tmp.split('/');
  
  // Clearing the output here
  $('div').html('');
  while(arr.length > 1) {
    tmp = 'http://' + arr.join('/');
    
    // Appending the current result
    $('div').append('<p>' + tmp + '/</p>');
    $('a[href="' + tmp + '"], a[href="' + tmp + '/"]').parent().addClass('active');
    arr = arr.slice(0,-1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="http://google.com/sub1/sub2">
<button id="test">test</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is awesome thanks a bunch! Cheeky I know, but do you know how I could amend this to make Parent "Active" when a subpage is selected, e.g. Site.com/TEST/Edit would still make the TEST link the Active property

Comment: Hey thanks, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work at all now!!

Comment: Updated again with a tester.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately not but I think I should be alright now. Thanks a lot for your effort I appreciate it.

Comment: Skatch - I don't know if this is of any use but the project is using MVC4. I still can't get the Child page to give the parent the active class. E.g. site.com/questions works fine and the active is applied. If I go to site.com/questions/create I want Questions to still remain the active class.

Comment: Yes, the first code in the **EDIT** part should work, debug the strings to see what is wrong, and no, it doesn't matter what you are using, this is dependent solely on javascript.